# Confirmar senha PHP, Javascript, HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

**Eu queria fazer a verificação de senha, se as senhas estiverem diferente aparecesse um alert com algo do tipo"Senhas não correspondem", se sim, passasse  direto. Mas do jeito que eu estou fazendo aparece uma mensagem do $mensagem "As senhas são iguais", mas mesmo assim está mando os dados pro banco.**

```
<?php 

    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nise', $username );

    $query = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, sobrenome, matricula, email, senha) 
          VALUES (:nome, :sobrenome, :matricula, :email, :senha)";

    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);


    $valores = array();
    $valores[':nome'] = (isset($_POST['primeiroNome']) ? $_POST['primeiroNome'] : '');
    $valores[':sobrenome'] = (isset($_POST['sobrenome']) ? $_POST['sobrenome'] : '');
    $valores[':matricula'] = (isset($_POST['matricula']) ? $_POST['matricula'] : '');
    $valores[':email'] = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '');
    $valores[':senha'] = (isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : '');






    $result = $statement->execute($valores);

        if($_POST) {
            $senha          = $_POST['senha'];
            $confirma_senha  = $_POST['confirma_senha'];
            if ($senha == "") {
                $mensagem = "<span class='aviso'><b>Aviso</b>: Senha não foi alterada!</span>";
            } else if ($senha == $confirma_senha) {
                $mensagem = "<span class='sucesso'><b>Sucesso</b>: As senhas são iguais: ".$senha."</span>";
            } else {
                $mensagem = "<span class='erro'><b>Erro</b>: As senhas não conferem!:".$confirma_senha."</span>";
            }
            echo "<p id='mensagem'>".$mensagem."</p>";
        }



    ?>
```

**Essa parte do script avisa se as senhas se correspondem, se sim ele não da nenhum alert, se não, aparece  um alert SENHAS DIFERENTES, mas quando eu aperto "OK" para fechar o alert os dados do formulário são removido e são enviado para o banco mesmo assim, e isso não era pra acontecer**

```
 <script> function validarSenha(){
        senha = document.formulario.senha.value
        confirma_senha = document.formulario.confirma_senha.value
        if (senha == confirma_senha) alert
        else alert("SENHAS DIFERENTES")
        }
   </script>
```

**E aqui está meu formulario**

```
<form method="POST" action="registro.php" name="formulario">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-row">
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="primeiroNome">Primeiro nome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="primeiroNome" name="primeiroNome" placeholder="Digite seu primeiro nome" required="required">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="Sobrenome">Sobrenome</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Sobrenome" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Digite seu Sobrenome" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6" id="matricula">
              <label for="primeiroNome">Matrícula</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="matricula" placeholder="Digite sua matrícula" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">E-mail</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu email" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-row">
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="confirma_senha">confirmar senha</label>
                    <input type="password"  class="form-control" id="confirmaSenha" name="confirma_senha" placeholder="Confirme sua senha" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div>
              <input type="submit"  onClick="validarSenha()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Registra-se"/>
           </div>
           <div class="text-center">
              <a href="#" class="d-block small mt-3">Esqueceu sua senha?</a>
              <a href="login.php" class="d-block small mt-3">Login?</a>
           </div>
        </form>
```

**Obs:Se Alguem tiver sugestões de alert mais bonito pode mandar...**

Comment: Fiz umas alterações na minha resposta. Teste tudo e comente se algo der errado ou se surgir outra dúvida sobre a resposta.

Comment: Manoo deu tudo certo, estava voltando só as chaves do script, valew mesmo cara já faz 6 hora que eu estava tentando fazer isso, mas sempre registrava no banco mesmo com as senha erradas. '----------'

Comment: Que ótimo que deu certo. Se surgir mais problemas abra novas perguntas. Sucesso!

Comment: Poderia me ajuda nessa pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/334660/queria-colocar-um-alert-na-minha-tela-de-login-php-js-html-mysql/334665#334665

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso tá acontecendo pois você tá chamando o `$statement->execute($valores)` antes das verificações. Por isso os registros serão inseridos independente do que as verificações constatarem. Tenta realocar esse código e usa ele como condição junto com a verificação da senha que aí sim o código se comportará da forma que você espera. Por exemplo:

```
<?php 

    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nise', $username );

    $query = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, sobrenome, matricula, email, senha) 
          VALUES (:nome, :sobrenome, :matricula, :email, :senha)";

    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);


    $valores = array();
    $valores[':nome'] = (isset($_POST['primeiroNome']) ? $_POST['primeiroNome'] : '');
    $valores[':sobrenome'] = (isset($_POST['sobrenome']) ? $_POST['sobrenome'] : '');
    $valores[':matricula'] = (isset($_POST['matricula']) ? $_POST['matricula'] : '');
    $valores[':email'] = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '');
    $valores[':senha'] = (isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : '');








        if($_POST) {
            $senha          = $_POST['senha'];
            $confirma_senha  = $_POST['confirma_senha'];
            if ($senha == "") {
                $mensagem = "<span class='aviso'><b>Aviso</b>: Senha não foi alterada!</span>";
            } else if ($senha == $confirma_senha && $statement->execute($valores)) {
                $mensagem = "<span class='sucesso'><b>Sucesso</b>: As senhas são iguais: ".$senha."</span>";

            } else {
                $mensagem = "<span class='erro'><b>Erro</b>: As senhas não conferem!:".$confirma_senha."</span>";
            }
            echo "<p id='mensagem'>".$mensagem."</p>";
        }



    ?>
```

Note que a condição de sucesso ficou `if ($senha == $confirma_senha && $statement->execute($valores))`. Surgeri ela assim, juntando  comparação das senhas com a execução do statement pois quando o  `$statement->execute($valores)` é feito com sucesso ele retorna um resultado booleando `true`, que será um dos determinantes para suprir a condição do `if` e exibir a mensagem de sucesso. Mais detalhes sobre o retorno do `statement` na documentação oficial: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php.

Sobre o javascript, mude algumas coisas, colocando retornos booleanos também, por exemplo:

```
<script> 
    function validarSenha(){
    senha = document.formulario.senha.value
    confirma_senha = document.formulario.confirma_senha.value
    if (senha == confirma_senha){
        return true
    }
    else{ 
        alert("SENHAS DIFERENTES")
        return false
    }
}
```

E depois retire essa função do `OnClick` do `submit` e a coloque como atributo da tag `<form>` dessa forma `onsubmit="return validarSenha()"`, ficando a tag do form semelhante a isso `<form method="POST" action="registro.php" onsubmit="return validarSenha()"name="formulario">`