# Queria colocar um alert na minha tela de login PHP, JS, HTML, MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5, ajax

**Eu queria colocar um alert na minha tela de login, se a matricula e senha se corresponderem o que está no banco passe direto, se não, aparecesse um alert ou as caixinha ficassem vermelha com o erro com algo do tipo "Matricula ou Senha errada"**

**está ai a conexão com meu banco**

```
<?php 
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nise', $username, $password );
?>
```

**Meu Controller**

```
<?php 
include 'usuarios/modelUsuario.php';

//se clicou no botão
if (isset($_POST['login'])){

    $modelo = new ModelUsuario();


    $resultado = $modelo->autenticar( ($_POST['matricula']), ($_POST['senha']) );
    if(! empty($resultado) ){
      // redirecionar para index2
      header("location: http://localhost/projeto/aluno.php"); 
    }

}

?>
```

**O modelo**

```
<?php
include 'usuarios/usuario.php';

class ModelUsuario{

    public function adicionar(){
        include 'usuarios/bd.php';

        $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (matricula, senha) 
              VALUES (:matricula, :senha)";

        $statement = $connection->prepare($query);

        $valores = array();
        $valores[':matricula'] = $usuario->getMatricula();
        $valores[':senha'] = $usuario->getSenha();


        $result = $statement->execute($valores);


    }

    public function editar(){

    }

    public function remover(){

    }


   public function autenticar($matricula, $senha){
        include 'usuarios/bd.php';


        $query = "SELECT nome, id FROM usuario WHERE matricula=:matricula and senha=:senha";


        $statement = $connection->prepare($query);

        $valores = array();
        $valores[':matricula'] = $matricula;
        $valores[':senha'] = $senha;


        $result = $statement->execute($valores);


        $result = $statement->fetchAll();



        return $result;

    }




}

?>
```

**E meu formulário**

```
 <form  method="POST" action ="login.php" name="for">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="matricula" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
                <label for="inputEmail">Matrícula</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-label-group">
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword"   name="senha" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required">
                <label for="inputPassword">Senha</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                  Lembrar senha
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="aluno.php" name="login">Login</button> 
                    <a href="registro.php" id="cadastro" class="d-block small mt-3">Cadastrar</a>
          </form>
```

OBS: O ALERT PODE SER NO JS OU AJAX, POR TANTO QUE ME AJUDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei muito bem como funciona o MVC e não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer isso, mas espero que possa ajuda você:
`$query` = "SELECT count(*) FROM usuario WHERE matricula=:matricula and senha=:senha", para saber se existe algum usuário com essa matricula e senha, logo você vai obter 0 ou 1 como resposta, já que o número de matricula é único.
E ao invés de usar fetchAll(), você pode usar fetchColumn() 
(Aqui o uso do mesmo -> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

Agora tô na dúvida se o 0 ou 1 você vai obter no model ou no controller. Imaginando que seja no controller, você pode usar uma condição de acesso permitido ou negado para o view. 
No view, não sei se você ta solicitando via ajax, mas se estiver use algo como:

```
$.post('controller.php', function (acesso){

 if(acesso === 'permitido')
 {

    window.location.href = 'aluno.php';

 }

 if(acesso === 'negado')
 {

    alert('acesso negado');  

 }

});
```

Como falei, não entendo muito de MVC, mas espero que esse processo ajude você.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode dar um `echo "<script> alert("texto aqui") </script>";` porém, imagino que você queira fazer uma modal, alerts não funcionam tão bem, principalmente em dispositivos móveis. Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://tableless.com.br/simples-modal-com-css-responsivo/)